# Why are these two generated JWTs different? (jwt.io vs postman)

Tags: jwt, postman, base64, jwt.io

I am trying to generate a JWT in Postman, and I don't understand why the token generated at jwt.io and Postman are different when Base64 Encoded is selected.

1. When the "Secret Base64 encoded" option is disabled, both tokens match.
2. When the "Secret Base64 encoded" option is enabled, the tokens are different, even though they are both using the same secret.

Any idea why the tokens would be different when Base64 Encoded is enabled?

[image: Base64 Encoded is disabled and Tokens Match]
[image: Base64 Encoded is enabled and Tokens Do Not Match]